# Amazon ECS task with two containers

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have set up Amazon ECS using Fargate, and the task definition contains two containers, one listening to port 9090 and the other to port 8080 . By creating a service and running the task, logs show that both services are up and running. Port mapping is also done in the container configuration of the task definition.

The security group used in the network interface of the task also allows both ports. (tested also by opening all ports)

But I can only access the service running on port 8080, and not the 9090!

Anything I am missing in the configuration? or any thoughts about what to check?

Comment: hi there, how are you accessing the containers? is your service fronted by an ApplicationLoadBalancer (ALB)

Comment: Hi Roy, I access them by the task's public IP and then port numbers. I tried the Classic Load Balancer first, because I am using multiple ports(based on the Amazon docs) but for the sake of simplicity removed it. Now running only that single task using the port 9090 and SecGroup which allows everything, still no luck! I run the container locally and it stays up and running for days, and ECS panel also shows it is running, so dont think that the container stops and the service is not responsive any longer

Comment: Can you confirm in your 9090 container's Dockerfile and task definition, you are declaring port 9090 as open to receive traffic? If it works locally, I'd lean more towards the task definition here...

Comment: Yes, the port mapping and the security group were configured for port 9090 as well. I have configured ALB from scratch and things are ok now, except some aws s3 access issues I have when the service is trying to putObject.